# ImageView causes NestedScrollView to automatically scroll upward

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageView inside RelativeView that is inside NestedScrollView, when I set the ImageView height it causes the an automatic upward scroll right after the inflation. This behaviour doesn't happen when I set the ImageView height to be wrap_content. What could be the reason? Is this some kind of bug in the support library?

**Notes:**

If I kept the ImageView height as 170 & removed the RelativeLayout this upward auto-scroll doesn't happen.

If I kept the RelativeLayout & set ImageView height to wrap_content this upward auto-scroll doesn't happen.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mydomain.test">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cover"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Update & Fix:**

Adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the vertical LinearLayout fixed the problem to be:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.mydomain.test">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/cover"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and the reason of the problem, In the code above I have the RelativeLayout inside a vertical LinearLayout, and when I added

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the vertical LinearLayout, the problem got fixed.